# How to return value from second page to jquery page

Tags: php, jquery

I need to get the value from second page `member_verify.php` in my jQuery resonse which is in first page. I need to get `$age` value in first page. Now message displays correctly.

I need to get the age which I fetched in `member_verify.php` with `$age=$fet['Age'];`:

```
function memberid(em) {
var memid=$("#memid").val();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'member_verify.php',
    data:{memid: memid},
    success:function(msg){
    if (msg.length> 0) {
        alert(msg);
    }
    else{
        $("#disableDiv :input").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    }

  });  
 } 

 member_verify.php
                <?php
              $s=$_POST['memid'];
              include "common/config.php";
              $echeck="select * from insmemberdetails where LoginId='".$_POST['memid']."'";
               $echk=mysqli_query($conn,$echeck);
               $fet=mysqli_fetch_assoc($echk);
               $age=$fet['Age'];
               $ecount=mysqli_num_rows($echk);
               if($ecount=='0')
               {
                  echo "Member Id Not exists";
               }else
               {   
                 $fet=mysqli_fetch_assoc($echk);
                 $verify=$fet['verify'];
                  if($verify=='0')
                   echo "Member Id not Verified";
               }

            ?>
```

Comment: you mean `echo $age;` ???

Comment: please explain more ... i do not think anyone would be able to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your member_verify.php to get age in ajax response otherwise you will get validation message.

```
<?php
    $s=$_POST['memid'];
    include "common/config.php";
    $echeck="select * from insmemberdetails where LoginId='".$s."'";
    $echk=mysqli_query($conn,$echeck);    
    $ecount=mysqli_num_rows($echk);
    if($ecount <= 0)
    {
      echo "Member Id Not exists";
    }    
    else
    {   
      $fet=mysqli_fetch_assoc($echk);
      $age=$fet['Age'];
      $verify=$fet['verify'];
      if($verify==0)
      {
       echo "Member Id not Verified";
      }
      else
      {
        echo $age; 
      } 
    }
?>
```

And below is your JS file.

```
function memberid(em) {
var memid=$("#memid").val();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'member_verify.php',
    data:{memid: memid},
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
    else{
        $("#disableDiv :input").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    }

  });  
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could know something about [json](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/).

php code:

```
if($ecount!=0){
  echo json_encode(array(
      errno: 0,
      data: $age
  )); 
}else{
  echo json_encode(array(
      errno: 500,
      errmsg: 'your error info'
  )); 
}
```

your js here:

```
$.ajax({
    // add this option
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you try that :

```
<?php
$age=$fet['Age'];
$champAgeExist = isset($age);
if (champAgeExist == true) {
   echo $age
?>
```